# NEXTJS, React, socketio, Rasberry Pi, DS18B20 - How to display in react hook?

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, next.js

I try to implement raspberry pi with DS18B20 by javascript/react/nextjs with socketio.
It's successful for the simple javascript/jquery with socketio.
But after I change to nextjs/reactjs with socketio, it's failed to display.

Please help to verify where I miss in the nextjs/reactjs code.

Success Code as below:

server.js

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(3000),
    ds18b20 = require('ds18b20');
 
var interval = 1000;
 
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
 
    var sensorId = [];
    ds18b20.sensors(function (err, id) {
        sensorId = id;
        socket.emit('sensors', id); //send sensor ID's to clients
    });
 
    setInterval(function () {
        sensorId.forEach(function (id) {
            ds18b20.temperature(id, function (err, value) {
                socket.emit('temps', {'id': id, 'value': value});
            });
        });
    }, interval);
});
```

server.js (update with express 4.17.1, socket.io 3.0.4)

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIO(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*"
  }
});

const ds18b20 = require('ds18b20');
const port = 3000;

const interval = 1000;

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  var sensorId = [];
  ds18b20.sensors((err, id) => {
    sensorId = id;
    socket.emit('sensors', id);
  });

  setInterval(() => {
    sensorId.forEach((id) => {
      ds18b20.temperature(id, (err, value) => {
        socket.emit('temps', {'id': id, 'value': value});
      });
    });
  }, interval);

});

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

index.html (client folder)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io.connect('http://172.20.10.5:3000'); // ip address related to server.js
        socket.on('sensors', function (data) { 
            data.forEach(function (d) {
                var html = '<tr><td>' + d + '</td><td id="' + d + '"></td></tr>';
                $('#temps').append(html);
            });
        });
        socket.on('temps', function (data) {
            $('#' + data.id).html(data.value);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>DS18B20 Temps</h1>

<div class="container">
    <table class="table" id="temps">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Sensor ID</th>
            <th>Temperature (celsius)</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js (client folder)

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 8080;

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.static('node_modules'));


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App listening at ${port}`);
});
```

[image]

ReactJS, which is fail to display.

server.js

```
const app = require('express')();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const next = require('next');

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const nextApp = next({dev});
const nextHandler = nextApp.getRequestHandler();

const ds18b20 = require('ds18b20');

let port = 3000;
let interval;

io.on("connect", (socket) => {
  console.log("New client conneccted");
  if (interval) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
  var sensorId = [];
  ds18b20.sensors((err, id) => {
    sensorId = id;
    socket.emit('sensors', id);
  });

  socket.on("Temp", () => {
    setInterval(() => {
      ds18b20.temperature(id, (err, value) => {
      io.emit("FromAPI",  
        JSON.stringify({
          id: id,
          value: value
        }));
      });
    }, interval);
  });

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("Client disconnected")
    clearInterval(interval)
  });
})
    
nextApp
  .prepare()
  .then(() => {

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    return nextHandler(req, res)
  });

  server.listen(port, (err) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(`Ready on port ${port}`);
  })
})
```

index.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import socketIOClient from 'socket.io-client';
import { Button, Input } from 'react-bootstrap';

const ENDPOINT = "http://172.20.10.5:3000";
const socket = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT);

function App() {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("FromAPI", data => {
      let temp = response;
      temp.push(JSON.parse(data));
      setResponse(temp);
    })
  }, [])

  return (
    <p>
      Temp is {response.value} degree celsius
    </p>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today, I get the answer and successfully display the result of temperature in the browser.
I just confuse about the variable of socketio.

Please see the success code as below:

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIO(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*"
  }
});

const ds18b20 = require('ds18b20');
const port = 4001;

const interval = 1000;

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  var sensorId = [];
  ds18b20.sensors((err, id) => {
    sensorId = id;
    socket.emit('sensors', id);
  });

  setInterval(() => {
    sensorId.forEach((id) => {
      ds18b20.temperature(id, (err, value) => {
        socket.emit('temps', {'id': id, 'value': value});
      });
    });
  }, interval);

});

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

index.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import socketIOClient from 'socket.io-client';
import { Table } from 'react-bootstrap';

const ENDPOINT = "http://10.10.12.165:4001";
const socket = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT);

function App() {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("temps", data => {
      setResponse(data);
    })
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>Realtime Temperature</h1>
        <Table responsive>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Sensor ID</th>
              <th>Temperature (celsius)</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>{response.id}</td>
              <td>{response.value}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </Table>
    </div>

  )
}

export default App;
```

The final result:

[image]